# refer to the plugin object within the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, plugins, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to access plugin through `this`, in order to refer to methods added later down in the chain.

```
$.fn.test = function(){

    console.log(this);
}
```

but `this` refers to the elements I have used to call the plugin, and not the plugin itself.

How can I access the plugin, and thus any methods attached to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` if you want the jQuery object.

You can also try this to add plugin to jQuery.

```
(function($){

    $.extend($.fn, {
        test: function(){
            //Plugin code here
            //here this will point to jQuery object
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```